# Find the actual displayed number of items per row in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, mac-catalyst

I have a **UICollectionView** of rectangular cells with mostly uniform size laid out with a stock **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**.

I am trying to implement keyboard arrow navigation in the *Catalyst* version of the App. Left and right are no problem. Here is a fully laid out example:

```
@objc func myRightKey() {
    var curr = glyphCollectionOutlet.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
    if curr == nil {curr = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)}
    if self.selectedCell == nil {self.selectedCell = curr} else {curr = self.selectedCell}
    let inSection = (curr!.section)
    // increment item in section up to max number of items
    let nextItem = curr!.item + 1
    let maxItem = glyphCollectionOutlet.numberOfItems(inSection: inSection) - 1
    let newItem = min(nextItem, maxItem)
    let newSelectPath = IndexPath(item: newItem, section: inSection)
    self.selectedCell = newSelectPath
    glyphCollectionOutlet.selectItem(at: newSelectPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
    glyphCollectionOutlet.reloadData()
}
```

The problem here is with up and down navigation which should place the selected cell directly above or below the starting point.  In *Mac* *Catalyst*, the **viewController** with the embedded **collectionView** can change width and thus change the number of cell/items in a row. Unfortunately, in a collectionView, the **IndexPath.row** is simply identical it seems to **IndexPath.item**, not at all related to displayed row.

I need to calculate the **IndexPath** of the next item which should be **N** items away from the current selection. It is true I can measure the current collectionView width, but the intercell spacing would still be variable.  Is there a way to dynamically calculate or detect the number of items displayed in a row so I can calculate **N**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to do that, but I believe there is an even better approach.

Why not take the center of the current cell, offset its `y` with the item height, and then check which index path is located there?

```swift
let currentCenter = cell.center
// Let's suppose you want to go downwards, just change to subtraction for going upwards
let targetCenter = CGPoint(currentCenter.x, currentCenter.y + cell.bounds.height) // Or however you want to consider the item height
let targetIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(targetCenter)
```

Also, this should work quite well for non-uniform item sizes as well.

Comment: Excellent! Works fine with a minor bug: the adjusted target Y value should be = CurrentY + bounds.Height/2 + offset for intercell spacing.  Many thanks!  Very clever!